# central point for kubernetes certificates

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

We have two on premise kubernetes clusters. And therefore we have the .kube/config files spread over the developers, as secret in github actions and a PRTG monitoring system where the sensors check with `kubectl get pods` if there are problems.

Every time the certificates are updated (kubeadm certs renew) all the machines will need to have the updates certificates.

Is it possible to automate this, so that certificates get distributed to anyone and all machines that need the config files?